# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' error in my React application when trying to display data from an API?

Tags: reactjs

How can I resolve the 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' error in my React application when trying to display data from an API? I have checked that the data is being fetched correctly and that the component is properly receiving the props but the error persists.

How can I resolve it.

Comment: Consider editing your question to add the code that generated the described error.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that somewhere in your code there's a line that contains

xxxx.map
or
xxxx.map(...)

and that at the moment that line is reached, xxxx is undefined.

You can resolve that by making sure that xxxx is defined before asking for it's map attribute or calling it's map() method.

Don't you have a stacktrace in your browser's console? That should point you to the place in your code where that xxxx.map is located.